# Can ruamel.yaml encode an enum?

Tags: python, enums, ruamel.yaml

The following is not working for me, with Python 3.4.7, ruamel.yaml version 0.15.35:

```
import sys
import enum

import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml import yaml_object
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

@yaml_object(yaml)
class Speed(enum.IntEnum):
    Reverse = 0
    Neutral = 1
    Low = 2
    Drive = 3
    Park = 999

print("Neutral:", repr(Speed.Neutral))

yaml.dump(Speed.Neutral, sys.stdout)
```

I get a totally reasonable `repr`:

```
Neutral: <Speed.Neutral: 1>
```

but the `.dump()` raises:

```
ruamel.yaml.representer.RepresenterError: cannot represent an object: <enum 'Speed'>
```

If `enum`'s are not supported, is there something I can do to extend the `enum` class I am using (or the subclass `enum.IntEnum` I have created), e.g. a dunder method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`enum` is not supported out-of-the-box, essentially because the default `dump` method is safe and therefore doesn't support arbitrary Python objects. That safety excludes types as `enum` from the standard library as well.

What you should do is add a `to_yaml` `classmethod` to your `Speed` class as described in the [ruamel.yaml documentation](http://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dumpcls.html?highlight=yaml_object#dumping-python-classes):

```
import sys
import enum

import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml import yaml_object
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

@yaml_object(yaml)
class Speed(enum.IntEnum):
    Reverse = 0
    Neutral = 1
    Low = 2
    Drive = 3
    Park = 999

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        return representer.represent_scalar(
            u'!Speed',
            '{}-{}'.format(node._name_, node._value_)
        )

yaml.dump(Speed.Neutral, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
!Speed Neutral-1
...
```

You can of course adapt the string representation to your liking (and add a `from_yaml` to be able to load the output back in).

Please note that you cannot add `yaml_tag` as in the documentation example, as this would interfere with the `enum` values.

Comment: and what if we don't have access to the class. E.g. what if we consume data from a 3rd party lib? Do we have to convert the enum to a string/integer manually?

Comment: If you don't have access to a class, you cannot use it, so there is never need to dump it. If you have access to a class, but cannot update/extend the `.py` it is in, there are other methods of making that class "known" to `ruamel.yaml`. That would be an excellent question for [so], but not an appropriate comment.

Comment: I get notified via email of any new question tagged ruamel.yaml, no need to notify me via a comment for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to pass the enum by value.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes

```
yaml.dump(Speed.Neutral.value, sys.stdout)
```

Extended answer to add a @classmethod which calls .value as it's being passed

http://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dumpcls.html

```
import sys
import enum
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml import yaml_object
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

@yaml_object(yaml)
class Speed(enum.IntEnum):
    Reverse = 0
    Neutral = 1
    Low = 2
    Drive = 3
    Park = 999

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        return representer.represent_scalar(u'!enum:', u'{.value}'.format(node))
```

Comment: That is a workaround, but it loses the type information, as I am then just encoding an int. YAML is able to preserve type and value for other objects. It feels like it should be able to do so for enums.